# Как соединить две колонки в одну?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, обработка-данных

Есть две колонки `data` и `vrem`. Нужно объединить их в одну, например, в `data_vrem`. Один раз у меня получилось, но я не смог их разъединить. То есть, данные в двух колонках `data` и `vrem` объединились в одну колонку, но данные были вставлены без пробела, то есть слитно.

Так как же мне объединить данные в одну строку, и чтобы они были через пробел?

[image: Колонки с данными]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените в вопросе как минимум картинку текстом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
txt["datetime"] = txt["data"].astype(str) + " " + txt["vrem"].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
```

Comment: Нету ключа

KeyError: 'data'

Comment: @The_Patrullerr, т.е. то, что вы указали в вопросе не соответствует действительности??

Comment: Нет, всё так. Но выдало мне вот такую ошибку.

Comment: @The_Patrullerr, в 77й ячейке Jupyter Notebook  вы читаете данные и укзаываете в качестве имени одного из столбцов `data` - как же так случилось что у вас нет такого столбца?? Что показывает `print(txt.columns.to_list())` если запустить эту команду сразу после `txt = pd.read\-csv(...)`??

Comment: Извиняюсь, это я просто не внимательный. Не обновил одну строку и ничего не получилось. Спасибо вам большое, мучался с этим два дня)