# Как заменить ноль на шесть нулей?

Tags: python, pandas, обработка-данных

Не могу сделать так, чтобы ноль, который находиться в конце колонки `vrem`, был написан не один раз, а шесть.

Как этого добиться?

[image: колонки]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230978/211923

Answer (score 6, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [Series.str.zfill(6)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)

```
txt["vrem"] = txt["vrem"].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
```

Comment: Спасибо, ноль заменился на шесть нулей. Не подскажите как сделать тоже самое с перемой ''datetime''?

Comment: @The_Patrullerr, посмотрите внимательно на __обновленный__ ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос